# How do you make clickable links / citations within a document?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I am trying to have clickable references where clicking the citation in the first section sends the reader to the reference in the second second. I cannot get this to work even after reading about this. How do I do this? And is it possible to do this without sections?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Main}\label{ref_section}

Here is some text \ref{ref_section}

\section{References}
\noindent [\ref{ref_section}] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilabe, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Done. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think you're looking for the commands `\hypertarget` (for setting an anchor a link goes to) and `\hyperlink` (for creating a link) from `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is an \hypertarget{anchor}{interesting fact} I want to refer to later.

\clearpage

As we saw \hyperlink{anchor}{earlier in the document} \ldots and later you will read \hyperref[coolsection]{a cool section}.

\clearpage

\section{My section name}\label{coolsection}

A really cool section.

\end{document}
```

`\ref` is only for referring (and, with the package, linking) to numbered items, like sections or equations or list items, using their number.

If you want to use arbitrary text to link to something marked with `\label{..}`, you can use `\hyperref[label]{text}`.

See the [hyperref documentation](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.pdf) for more.

EDIT: If you want two links to link to each other, you can wrap the links themselves inside target anchors, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is \hypertarget{top}{\hyperlink{bottom}{both an anchor and a link}}.

\clearpage

This is \hypertarget{bottom}{\hyperlink{top}{also both an anchor and a link}}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've seen a little erratum: **\hypertaget**, instead of **\hypertarget**.

Comment: @karloswitt Fixed thanks.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you. That seems to do almost exactly what I want. The only thing is - how would I link the two parts to each other? \hyperlink gives a clickable link to \hypertarget, but how do you make both clickable to point to each other? I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @GnuBe Yes, that makes sense. See the edits to the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing this up! Really helpful.